# Multibit balance per address

Tags: multibit

I have a Multibit wallet with 2 receiving addresses and of course 2 associated private keys.

I am shown the current balance contained in the wallet but there is no breakdown of this balance according to which address/key holds exactly how much of it.  It seems like a strange oversight not to show this information?

I can go through the transaction log and see the transactions relating to each address and thereby work out how much of the balance is associated with each address, but this is arduous work for a person and a walk in the park for a computer!  So why doesn't it do it?

Or have I missed something?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

All transactions are added to the blockchain. If you need to use the bitcoins associated with a single address for payment, it will refer to the particular transaction from which it has received the bitcoins. The wallet stores each transaction separate so that you can see the transaction details (txid, sender, receiver, etc). Even though it shows the cumulative value of all the addresses, you don't have to worry of how much each address stores since the software will take care of combining multiple transaction outputs if need be. It would be easier to see the combined value of each address but then it makes it tougher to store individual transactions.

Comment: "It would be easier to see the combined value of each address but then it makes it tougher to store individual transactions." What do you mean with that? Why would it be harder to store individual transactions?